# Creating contextual classifier in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, vs-extensibility

I'm writing a simple extension for visual studio that should provide syntax highlighting. It works fine for contextless scenarios where I just use regex to identify text span class:

```
internal class SolKeyword : IClassifier
{
    private readonly List<(Regex, IClassificationType)> _map;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SolKeyword"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="registry">Classification registry.</param>
    internal SolKeyword(IClassificationTypeRegistryService registry)
    {
        _map = new List<(Regex, IClassificationType)>
        {
            (new Regex(@"/\*.+\*/", RegexOptions.Compiled), registry.GetClassificationType(Classification.SolComment)),
            (new Regex(@""".*?""", RegexOptions.Compiled), registry.GetClassificationType(Classification.SolString)),
            (new Regex($@"\b({string.Join("|", VerboseConstant.BuiltinTypes.Concat(VerboseConstant.Keywords))})\b", RegexOptions.Compiled), registry.GetClassificationType(Classification.SolKeyword)),
            (new Regex($@"\b({VerboseConstant.Operators})\b", RegexOptions.Compiled), registry.GetClassificationType(Classification.SolKeyword)),
            (new Regex(@"-?(\d+(\.\d*)*)|(\.\d+)", RegexOptions.Compiled), registry.GetClassificationType(Classification.SolNumber)),
        };
    }
}

...
```

And then it's used via standard mechanism:

```
[Export(typeof(IClassifierProvider))]
[ContentType("sol")]
internal class SolEditorClassifierProvider : IClassifierProvider
{
    // Disable "Field is never assigned to..." compiler's warning. Justification: the field is assigned by MEF.
#pragma warning disable 649

    /// <summary>
    /// Classification registry to be used for getting a reference
    /// to the custom classification type later.
    /// </summary>
    [Import]
    private IClassificationTypeRegistryService classificationRegistry;

#pragma warning restore 649

    #region IClassifierProvider

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a classifier for the given text buffer.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="buffer">The <see cref="ITextBuffer"/> to classify.</param>
    /// <returns>A classifier for the text buffer, or null if the provider cannot do so in its current state.</returns>
    public IClassifier GetClassifier(ITextBuffer buffer)
    {
        return buffer.Properties.GetOrCreateSingletonProperty<SolKeyword>(creator: () => new SolKeyword(this.classificationRegistry));
    }
...
```

However, i'm stuck contextual classes like `struct`. I need to add functionallity as if there is `struct Foo` anywhere in text file then all `Foo`'s should be highlighted. So my question is how could it be implemented and how could it work appropriately with typing (when `Foo` is changed to `Bar` or something). I think I may somehow use some type of aggregation in `GetClassifier` method but I'm not sure it's the right way to do it.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to highlight all members, variables and etc. that are `Foo` type? If so you can't do that just use a regular expression. I suggest to try Roslyn for analyzing or something else. About typing: when some text was changed VS invoke `IClassifier.GetClassificationSpans(...)` for all `TextSpan` that can be affected by changes. And during invocation you will need to analyze input `TextSpan` and filter it by your logic. If I rigth understood your case you can look at a [extension](https://github.com/GeorgeAlexandria/CoCo) that do the similar logic during highlighted.

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria I forget about this question. I actually did it, but I forgot to write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found some workaround.

Just like before, we have a classifier:

```
internal class SolKeyword : IClassifier
{
    private readonly List<(Regex, IClassificationType)> _map;
    private readonly IClassificationType _typeClassification;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SolKeyword"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="registry">Classification registry.</param>
    internal SolKeyword(IClassificationTypeRegistryService registry)
    {
        _map = new List<(Regex, IClassificationType)>
        {
            (new Regex(@"/\*.+\*/", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Multiline), registry.GetClassificationType(Classification.SolComment)),
            (new Regex(@"//.+", RegexOptions.Compiled), registry.GetClassificationType(Classification.SolComment)),
            (new Regex(@""".*?""", RegexOptions.Compiled), registry.GetClassificationType(Classification.SolString)),
            (new Regex($@"\b({string.Join("|", VerboseConstant.BuiltinTypes.Concat(VerboseConstant.Keywords))})\b", RegexOptions.Compiled), registry.GetClassificationType(Classification.SolKeyword)),
            (new Regex($@"\b({VerboseConstant.Operators})\b", RegexOptions.Compiled), registry.GetClassificationType(Classification.SolKeyword)),
            (new Regex(@"\b-?(\d+(\.\d*)*)|(\.\d+)", RegexOptions.Compiled), registry.GetClassificationType(Classification.SolNumber)),
        };

        _typeClassification = registry.GetClassificationType(Classification.SolType);
    }
```

but now we have following code that shows all types:

```
    public IList<ClassificationSpan> GetClassificationSpans(SnapshotSpan span)
    {
        IList<ClassificationSpan> list = new List<ClassificationSpan>();
        ITextSnapshotLine line = span.Start.GetContainingLine();
        string text = line.GetText();

        foreach (var tuple in _map)
        {
            AddMatchingHighlighting(tuple.Item1, text, line, list, tuple.Item2);
        }

        string fullFileText = span.Snapshot.GetText();
        var contracts = Regex.Matches(fullFileText, @"(?:contract|struct|enum)\W+([\w_]+)", RegexOptions.Compiled).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value);
        var matchingItems = new Regex($@"\b({string.Join("|", contracts)})\b");
        AddMatchingHighlighting(matchingItems, text, line, list, _typeClassification);

        return list;
    }

    private static void AddMatchingHighlighting(Regex regex, string text, ITextSnapshotLine line, ICollection<ClassificationSpan> list, IClassificationType classificationType)
    {
        foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(text))
        {
            var str = new SnapshotSpan(line.Snapshot, line.Start.Position + match.Index, match.Length);

            if (list.Any(s => s.Span.IntersectsWith(str)))
                continue;

            list.Add(new ClassificationSpan(str, classificationType));
        }
    }
```

Now it works as expected. It may give false positives (because it doesn't use sematic analysis) and it show only types declared in the same file, but it was ok to me.